# Java concurrency in practice - safe publication, immutable object and volatile

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm reading "Java concurrency in practice" and one thing is confusing me.

```java
class OneValueCache {
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

    public OneValueCache(BigInteger lastNumber, BigInteger[] lastFactors) {
        this.lastNumber = lastNumber;
        this.lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }

    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
        if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i)) {
            return null;
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }
}

class VolatileCachedFactorized implements Servlet {
    private volatile OneValueCache cache = new OneValueCache(null, null);

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);

        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
        }

        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
    }
}
```

In above code author uses `volatile` with reference to immutable `OneValueCache`, but a few page later he writes:

`Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional synchronization, even when synchronization is not used to publish them.`

So .. `volatile` is not necessary in above code?

Comment: `cache` is not a cache, it is a reference to a cache.  The reference needs to be volatile in order that the switch of cache is visible to all threads.

Comment: Ok, but `Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional synchronization, even when synchronization is not used to publish them.` denies it.

Comment: My comments were getting long enough to make me think I should post an answer. See there.

Answer (score 2):

There are kind of 2 level of "thread-safety" that is being applied here. One is at reference level ( done using `volatile`). Think of an example where a thread reads the value to be null vs other thread seeing some reference value ( changed in between). Volatile will guarantee the publication of one thread is visible to another. But aAnother level of thread safety will be required to safeguard the internal members themselves which have the potential to be changed. Just having a volatile will have no impact on the data within the Cache ( like lastNumber, lastFactors). So immutability will help in that case.

As a general rule ( referred [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/CON50-J.+Do+not+assume+that+declaring+a+reference+volatile+guarantees+safe+publication+of+the+members+of+the+referenced+object)) as a good thread safe programming practice

> Do not assume that declaring a reference volatile guarantees safe
> publication of the members of the referenced object

This is the same reason why putting a volatile keyword in front of a HasMap variable does not make it threadsafe.

Comment: Thank You, I understand this, but I ask one more time: does safety means that object is in consistent state, but not necessarly most freshed?

Comment: Definition of thread safety is simple - A class is thread-safe when it continues to behave correctly when accessed from multiple threads. But the "Correct" behaviour depends on how you intend it to behave. For e.g. if you are incrementing a shared integer ( using i++) from multiple thread it is not thread-safe - multiple thread might see stale value and increment the same number to next integer. So you use a thread safe class "AtomicInteger" because you expected each thread to see only refreshed data. Also you would want that the internals of the object should also be in consistent state.

Comment: Check this extremely old ( 1998) article but still very relevant on thread safety https://www.artima.com/articles/designing-for-thread-safety

Answer (score 0):

`cache` is not a cache, it is a reference to a cache. The reference needs to be volatile in order that the switch of cache is visible to all threads.

Even after assignment to `cache`, other threads may be using the old cache, which they can safely do. But if you want the new cache to be seen as soon as it is switched, volatile is needed. There is still a window where threads might be using the old cache, but volatile guarantees that subsequent accessors will see the new cache. Do not confuse 'safety' with 'timeliness'.

Another way to look at this is to note that immutability is a property of the cache object, and cannot affect the use of any reference to that object. (And obviously the reference is not immutable, since we assign to it).

Comment: Ok, so `safety` means that object is in `consistent` state, but not necessarly most freshed?

Comment: The issue is not in the object, it is in the variable.  Assume thread 1 has just assigned a value to `cache`. Without volatile, thread 2 will read a reference to some OneValueCache object, but it is not necessarily the one just assigned.  With volatile, thread 2 will see the reference to the latest instance.  This is nothing to do with the object at all. It is the variable that might appear stale to some threads.